# AdMob Banner: Not enough space to show ad

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm tring to show a Google's banner inside my application. I've this layout (activity_main):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"     
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>      

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>      

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

When i run my app i see in the logcat this error:

```
Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 360x0 dp.
```

How can i fix it and show the banner? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `FrameLayout` and `RelativeLayout` `width` should be `wrap_content`, or 0dp and `weight` equals to 1 for both or other proportions if you want, the reason for this issue is that your `FrameLayout` `witdh` is set to `match_parent`

And if you want to use `weight` you should change your `LinearLayout` orientation to `horizontal`

Comment: Also wrapping AdView within RelativeLayout is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` to the activity in your `manifest` file.

Hope this will help.